# Flutter Firebase: get documents where a particular fiels is not null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch documents where `callerId` fields does not contain null value

I tries this

```dart
final collection =
        _firestoreService.instance.collection(TIME_SLOTS_COLLECTION_NAME);

Query query = collection
  .where("listenerId", isEqualTo: _userService.user!.firestoreId!)
  .where("callerId", isNull: false)
  .orderBy("startTime", descending: true);

print("after query");
```

But it returns nothing. Code after this statement does not run at all. It means `after query` does not get printed on the console. I am not sure what's the problem?

I tried this

```dart
final collection =
        _firestoreService.instance.collection(TIME_SLOTS_COLLECTION_NAME);

Query query = collection
  .where("listenerId", isEqualTo: _userService.user!.firestoreId!)
  .where("callerId", isEqualTo: "caller1")
  .orderBy("startTime", descending: true);

print("after query");
```

It runs but the first one does not. Does anyone know something about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the [FlutterFire implementation of `isNull`](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview/):

> ```
> if (isNull != null) {
>   assert(
>       isNull,
>       'isNull can only be set to true. '
>       'Use isEqualTo to filter on non-null values.');
>   addCondition(field, '==', null);
> }
> ```

So it looks like your condition is invalid, and you should be seeing an error message in your program output. That also explains why the app stops working: the assertion fails, and thus your app crashes.

You can use `isNotEqualTo` (or `>`, `>=` and others) to filter here:

```
.where("callerId", isNotEqualTo: false)
```

What I find really helpful in cases such as this is to keep the table of [supported data types and their sort order](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#data_types) handy.

Comment: But `callerId` can take any value so how would I `isNotEqualTo` to fetch all docs having non null `callerId` value?

Comment: I picked `false` pretty arbitrarily here. As it sounds like `callerId` is a string field, it will never have a boolean value. Did you try the query?

Comment: Hey @jastor_007 Did you make any progress on this?